# Avoiding modulo operator or branching to feed a circular buffer?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, modulo

For an FIR convolution, I have a doubled delay line (circular buffer) that I feed 4 samples at a time.

To be able to put samples on the 2nd half of the buffer, I have to use modulo operator.

However, the use of the modulo operator is **very slow**.

How the buffer is being fed:

```
for (var sample = 0; sample <= length - CVector; sample += CVector)
{
    var s0 = ZOffset + 0;
    var s1 = ZOffset + 1;
    var s2 = ZOffset + 2;
    var s3 = ZOffset + 3;

    Z[s0] = Z[(s0 + ZOffsetSet) % ZLength] = source[sample + 3];
    Z[s1] = Z[(s1 + ZOffsetSet) % ZLength] = source[sample + 2];
    Z[s2] = Z[(s2 + ZOffsetSet) % ZLength] = source[sample + 1];
    Z[s3] = Z[(s3 + ZOffsetSet) % ZLength] = source[sample + 0];
    ...
}
```

The content of `Z` after each iteration:

```
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  7,  6,  5
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5
  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0,  0, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5
  4,  3, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5
 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7, 32, 31
```

(the fed signal is 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 29, 30, 31, 32)

This is how each index gets adjusted using modulo operator:

```
26 -> 26
27 -> 27
28 -> 28
29 -> 29
...
50 -> 50
51 -> 51
52 -> 0
53 -> 1
```

Obviously, I can use `if (index >= Z.Length) index -= Z.Length;` but that adds branching.

**Question:**

How can I avoid using modulo or branching to get the right indices for the circular buffer?

Comment: Is `ZLength` a power of 2 by any chance?  That would let you perform a simple modulus with a bitwise `& (ZLength - 1)`  What is the maximum value of `ZOffsetSet`?  Because that may open up opportunities to duplicate the samples at the end of the buffer so that modulus is not required.

Comment: And are you certain that you're paying a penalty for branching?  And are you confident the penalty is severe?  (It shouldn't be)  It looks like you'll pay the cost exactly once per wraparound, which may be just once?  I'm not sure of your access pattern.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, no, it isn't necessarily a power of two.

Comment: Well, that is more or less a guess, avoiding branching means less code which means it'll be faster.

Comment: Have you considered writing the performance critical portion of this in C++ using `std::rotate_copy`?  Are you using an unsafe context with pointers?  (will likely help improve speed).  Also, consider writing contiguously in the order s0, s1, s2, s3, s0+z, s1+z, s2+z, s3+z instead of zig-zagging: s0+z, s0, s1+z, s1, s2+z, s2, s3+z, s3. Also Instead of computing each address individually, consider writing a single check to see where the source crosses the destination gap and just call one (or two) contiguous Array range copies (Array.Copy or Buffer.BlockCopy). And always _measure_ performance!

Comment: That code will end up as native code compiled by Unity Burst, it'll be fast, but still, the modulo can be felt. You just gave me two ideas, try a power of 2 delay line and see if it will work, else, generate tables; that last one for sure will solve both problems although it becomes harder to debug then.

Comment: Extending the delay line to the next pow2 worked without any other change required. Now I have to decide myself, having a much longer Z or tables both with their own debugging quirks. I'll sleep on it first!

Comment: If `ZLength` is known at compile-time, then compilers can generate a code not using a modulo but a sequence of cheap instructions. This means You have to generate several variants of this function for different size (possibly using a table, no need to replicate the function code). An alternative solution is to use floating-point operations to make that faster if `s0 + ZOffsetSet` is guaranteed to be small. It seems crazy at first glance but FP operations are better vectorized than integer ones. Thus, computing 4 FP modulus will often be significantly faster then integer one on most CPUs.